# content security policy issue with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

Trying to load different contents(can be pdf, swf etc.) in an 'iframe' through javascript in an chrome extension application. The content is loaded using the data URL scheme as :

// this javascript is registered in the html file and the LoadFunction is registered inside the DOMContentLoaded event on the click of a button.

```
void LoadFunction()
{
window.parent.document.getElementById("page_data").src = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'    + 'base64 encoded data'; (base64 data is received from a c++ class)
}
```

but as soon as above function is called, a content security policy error is raised as :

**Refused to load plugin data from 'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQNCiXi48/TDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL1R5cGU…mRvYmoNCjkgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvRm9udA0KL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUxDQovQmFzZUZ' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'**

But surprisingly this error is NOT raised when the data url is changed to  :  'data:image/png;base64,' + 'base64 encoded data'; and the image gets loaded into iframe successfully.

As far as i know, this error is raised only when inline code is executed directly into html file but this isn't the case here and if that is the case then why it does not gets raised for image files.

Also if i try setting the content security policy in the manifest.json file as : 
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self' ; frame-src 'self' data:"

then the error changes to : 
**Refused to load plugin data from 'data:application/pdf;base64,' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'self'**

so probably object-src needs to be set, but not sure what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of the Chrome extension's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html),

> Note that both script-src and object-src are defined by the policy. Chrome will not accept a policy that doesn't limit each of these values to (at least) 'self'.

It is not possible to relax your extemsion's CSP to accept the PDF.
**However**...

You can define a [sandboxed extension resource](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox.html), i.e. a page within your extension that is not affected by the extension's CSP. At the same time, the page will lose its access to the Chrome extension API, to protect against security vulnerabilities in your page. If you wish to communicate between your extension and the sandboxed page, use `postMessage` - e.g. as shown at [Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval.html).

Comment: But how does then CSP allowed to use image type in the data URI scheme ,as i used : 'data:image/png;base64,successfully. Is it mime type dependent or else?

Comment: @user3074358 `data:application/pdf,..` results in an attempt to load content through a plugin (object), whereas `data:image/png,` is just an image. If you want to block `data:image/png` as well, add `frame-src 'self'` to your CSP.

Comment: Ok, i tried loading the pdf using the sandbox way. Created an iframe in sandboxed' html and created the source for that iframe during run-time by communicating between non-sand box page and the sandbox one. Now there are no errors in the console window but for some reasons the pdf isn't visible in the frame.Also if i choose the 'inspect element' and go the iframe created and click the link(which is 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data) in front of its 'src' tag then pdf opens fine in a new tab. I have already check the chrome://plugins to see if pdf viewer is enabled.

Comment: Odd. I suggest to use [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) for embedding the PDF. Then you'll also be certain that the PDF will always be viewed inline (Only Chrome has a built-in PDF Viewer).

Comment: well i need to display various contents on UI, so its not just only PDF.The content can be a PDF, SWF etc., so i was hoping that this should run (i.e. providing different mime types for different contents plus the base64 encoded string to the iframe src.), but not sure what wrong is going on. Apart from this, i also tried adding a 'embed' element in the html during run-time instead of iframe as :     <embed name="frame_page" id="frameContent" width="50%" height="50%"     src="data:application/pdf;base64+encoded string" type="application/pdf"> , but still the result is same.

Comment: Just an update, if i try loading the pdf file from a local folder(excluding base64 logic for time being) inside an iframe of sandbox html page, the iframe remain empty and console raises a warning : **Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "chrome-extension://bnpefkceeenoedolfljiaiebpeaecnkc/TestFiles/PDFName.pdf"** , the code executed from js file to fill the iframe is : 'window.frames['page_frame'].src ="TestFiles/PDFName.pdf"' , however  if the same code is executed from a normal(non sandbox) page then pdf file loads successfully.

Comment: @user3074358 I've just checked, and embedding `data:application/x-shockwave-flash` works just fine (using the [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox.html) feature). Note that you've use the feature as follows: 1. Embed the sandboxed page in an iframe. 2. Embed the external content in another iframe within the sandboxed page.