# Content security policy syntax for base64 data uris

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm trying to programatically alter a pdf preview page inside a chrome extension that extends devtools.

**manifest**

```
  "content_security_policy": "img-src 'self' data; script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; data-uri 'self'"
```

When I set the `src` attribute to an iframe I can successfully load the pdf and it will be generated dynamically.

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,..."></iframe>
```

However, when I try the same for an `embed` or `object` html element I get:

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,...">
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,..."></object>
```

> Refused to load plugin data from 'data:application/pdf;base64,{{data}}' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'self'".

Why? Resetting the `src` attribute on an iframe is giving focus to the nested content window, so when the user is typing in the parent window suddenly the `textarea` is blurred (it's really annoying). I thought that using an `embed` or `object` element would mitigate the nested document problem.

What is the correct csp syntax in order to get embeds working correctly? I'm looking directly at the [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directives) docs it's not really helping. For instance, I tried the following syntax in my manifest:

```
"content_security_policy": "object-src 'self' data"
```

...which will throw an error when you try to refresh the extension in `chrome://extensions`.

Comment: Does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423733/content-security-policy-issue-with-chrome-extension) help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that it works for `<iframe>` is that that the extension's default [Content security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) does not block any frames. It only restricts scripts and plugins.

The relevant part of the CSP for plugins is:

```js
object-src 'self' blob: filesystem:
```

On normal web pages, you would use <del>`"content_security_policy": "object-src 'self' blob: filesystem: data:"`</del> to allow data:-URLs to be embedded. This is [not allowed in extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing), so you cannot load `data:`-URLs in plugins. If you try to add this "data:" directive anyway, then it will be ignored. When developer mode and "Collect errors" is enabled at `chrome://extensions`, the error log (*not* the JS console) will display:

> Ignored insecure CSP value "data:" in directive 'object-src'.

To load a PDF in an extension via `<embed>` or `<object>`, try one of the whitelisted schemes:

```js
var pdfBlob = new Blob(['%PDF raw pdf data here...'], {
    type:'application/pdf'
});
var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);

var embed = document.createElement('embed');
embed.src = pdfUrl;
embed.type = 'application/pdf';  // Optional
document.body.appendChild(embed);
```

Answer (score 4):

[According to the CSP spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#source-list), 
you need to specify schemes as `scheme:` (with colon), not just `scheme`. So, you need to change the directive to:

```
"content_security_policy": "object-src 'self' data:"
```